# css3 border-image not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, compass-sass, border-image

I have tried to implement an "envelope border" effect on my page.

Basically, it's the same as this in codepen:

http://codepen.io/danichk/pen/KdorYJ

---

```
  .box {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 16px solid transparent;<br>
    border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    max-width: 20em;
    font: 100%/1.6 Baskerville, Palatino, serif;
  }
```

---

But it doesn't work in safari. And I also found that even the example of 'border-image' in w3schools seems not working. Which already consider multi-browser supported.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image3

In fact, I have also tried compass to generate a "multi-browser" friendly css as below:

compass:

```
$envelop-border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
.envelope-border {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 16px solid transparent;
  @include border-image($value: $envelop-border-image);
}
```

css

```
.envelope-border {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 16px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: 16 -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    -moz-border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    -o-border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    -webkit-border-image: 16 -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    -webkit-border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    border-image: 16 -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    border-image: 16 -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
 }
```

Does anybody have any idea about it? Many thanks.

My Safari version is: Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
border-width: 16px;
```

for the `.box` class.

Webkit has a bug with `border-style` and `border-width`. If no definition of `border-style` will show `border-image`. So you only need `border-width`

```
.box {
    padding: 1em;
    border-width: 16px;
    border-image: 16 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    max-width: 20em;
    font: 100%/1.6 Baskerville, Palatino, serif;

  }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

it seems can be solved by this little trick.

```
.envelope-border {
  padding: 0;
  border: 16px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: 16 -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #58a 0, #58a 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
}

.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

html

```
<div class="envelope-border">
  <div class="content"><div>
</div>
```